# How to loop through object with different keynames, but same placement

Tags: javascript

I have an object where there are different variables for the amount of cows (cows as an example), and the object does not follow any particular pattern.

```
var cow = [
            //{variable: amount, name: "name"},
            {redcow: 0, name: "Redcow"},
            {bluecow: 0, name: "Bluecow"},
            {yellowcow: 0, name: "Yellowcow"}, 
            {purplecow: 0, name: "Purplecow"},
            {greencow: 0, name:"Greencow"}]
```

Now I want to make a loop that cycles through the different types of cows and checks for the amount of each type of cow, and then output the **name** and **amount**.

Comment: Great, then make it!

Comment: But I need help :/ Since I can't loop through with a variable with cow.(variablename) since they have different names.

Comment: does the name correlates to the key (in lowercase) of the amount?

Comment: @NinaScholz: It looks like it, and that's what I used in my answer.

Comment: The names will be used as output, trying all of the answers now :)

Comment: @Bjartfjord, so no, or?

Comment: Why do you have different keys in each object in the first place?

Comment: @NinaScholz Answer's no, since the formatting of the output depends on the name, as in, the uppercase letter is the start of the sentence.

Comment: @Barmar There is some math going on in in my original code. I used cows to try make the question easier to understand :)

Comment: @Bjartfjord, but you have only two proerties, and you know one.

Comment: @NinaScholz the amount property will get calculated in my original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and use only the one which is not equal than name.

```js
var cow = [{ redcow: 1, name: "Redcow" }, { bluecow: 2, name: "Bluecow" }, { yellowcow: 3, name: "Yellowcow" }, { purplecow: 4, name: "Purplecow" }, { greencow: 5, name: "Greencow" }];

cow.forEach(function (o) {
    var countKey;
    Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'name') {
            countKey = k;
            return true;
        }
    });
    console.log(o.name, o[countKey]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but your data structure is kinda broken.
Why don't you use

```
{amount: 0, name: "Redcow"}
```

instead of

```
{redcow: 0, name: "Redcow"}
```

?

Then it will be trivial to display name and amount.

If you really want to use this structure and the amount key is the lowercase name :

```js
var cows = [
            //{variable: amount, name: "name"},
            {redcow: 3, name: "Redcow"},
            {bluecow: 5, name: "Bluecow"},
            {yellowcow: 4, name: "Yellowcow"}, 
            {purplecow: 2, name: "Purplecow"},
            {greencow: 1, name:"Greencow"},
            {whatevercow: 99, name:"Orangecow"}
];

for (i = 0; i < cows.length; i++) {
    var cow = cows[i];
    var name = cow.name;
    var count = cow[name.toLowerCase()];
    console.log(name, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cow = [
    {
        redcow: 0,
        name: "Redcow"
    }, {
        bluecow: 0,
        name: "Bluecow"
    }, {
        yellowcow: 0,
        name: "Yellowcow"
    }, {
        purplecow: 0,
        name: "Purplecow"
    }, {
        greencow: 0,
        name: "Greencow"
    }
];

cow.forEach(function(item) {
    var count = {
        name: item.name,
        amount: item[Object.keys(item)[0]]
    }
    console.log(count);
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Not sure your solution addresses the problem, if another key was added?

Comment: thats really a problem if the wanted key has no pattern to use.